# Having file/folder as private/invisible to others only on Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I am aware of the functionality of `.gitignore`. I was wondering whether it is possible to push a folder or a file to the remote-host (in my case Gitlab) but have only that one folder or file there to be private (or invisible) in such a way that upon cloning, others also would not be able to clone those specific single folders/files? Has any one done something like this on Gitlab before? The use case is that I simply want to have a backup of some data on the Gitlab, without exposing them to anyone.

Comment: "I was wondering whether it is possible to push a folder or a file to the remote-host (in my case Gitlab) but have only that one folder or file there to be private (or invisible) in such a way that upon cloning" - no, it isn't, because it would break `git`'s fundamental property of using a content-addressable object store.

Comment: Agreed with Dai - just for completeness though, you could potentially store some of what you're looking for in a private snippet associated with your account. It's not in a Git repo that way, but still stored in GitLab.